# Display JSON Array Result in Spotfire DataTable using ironPython

Tags: json, ironpython, spotfire

I have a JSON String array (Result from a REST API call) as shown below. That string array should be organized as Column Names and Respective Records in a Data Table in Spotfire Using IronPython Script. 
All the attributes should be displayed as my column names (only for once) and values should be displayed as records (iterate).
Any Help is much Appreciated.
Please let me know if you need more Clarity.

JSON Data:

[{"actionType":"Adjust Tubing or Casing PSI","assignedTeam":"FS","exceptionStatus":"","eventEndDate":"1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","description":"Motor Temperature","lastEditedDate":"2019-07-19T02:49:00.945Z","well":{"apiNumber12":"423294206100","area":"MIDLAND BASIN","wellName":"C SCHARB 31WB","asset":"ODESSA EAST FMT","route":"4000003 - NOD","apiNumber14":"42329420610001"},"actionItemPastDueDate":"2019-07-27T02:48:59.000Z","lastEditedBy":"Agent(System-Queue-ServiceLevel.ProcessEvent)","priorityRangeMax":500.000000000,"currentStage":"ALT5","id":"E-4056","workOrder":"","assignedDate":"2019-07-15T05:00:00.000Z","impactedLpo":true,"alcrApprovalComments":"","createdDate":"2019-07-16T02:48:34.786Z","alcrApprovalDeadline":"2019-07-19T02:48:59.000Z","dueDate":"2019-07-22T02:48:59.000Z","chemicalAdvisorComments":"","recommendationsStripped":"Training Test","workStatus":"Pending-ALCRApproval","actionTakenStripped":"","recommendations":"

Training Test

","tier":"6","cancelationComments":"","priority":"5","woSubmitted":false,"daysTillActionItemDue":"","eventStartDate":"2019-07-16T02:48:37.276Z","assignedTo":"","currentCommentsStripped":"","fsActionItemNearDueDate":"1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","cancelDate":"1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","averageBoed":374,"fsActionItemPastDueDate":"1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","lpoUom":"barrels per day","lpoRate":374,"surfaceWorkRequired":false,"liftMethod":"ESP","originatorCai":"alwo.coeesp","actionItemNearDueDate":"2019-07-21T02:48:59.000Z","createdBy":"Centaur COE ESP","priorityRangeMin":250.000000000,"functionalGroup":"ESP COE"}]

(Above is the Edited JSON of one single record)

```
uri = "https://quantprice.herokuapp.com/api/v1.1/scoop/period?tickers=MSFT&begin=2012-02-19"
webRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(uri)
response = webRequest.GetResponse()
from System.IO import StreamReader
from System.Web.Script.Serialization import JavaScriptSerializer
streamReader = StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
jsonData = streamReader.ReadToEnd()
js = JavaScriptSerializer()
dataDict = js.Deserialize(jsonData,object)


# build a string representing the data in tab-delimited text format
myColName = []  
for val in dataDict["stations"]:
    myColName.append(val["id"])
textData =     "\t".join(myColName) + "\r\n"
print textData

for quote in dataDict["stations"]:
    print "\t".join(str(val) for val in quote)
    textData += "\t".join(str(val) for val in quote) + "\r\n"

print textData
```

If i do this, my Result set is showing [column name, column value] as rows.
But, i want "Column name" as my header list and "Column Values" as my Rows.